# Populate next empty cell with value above plus 1 until all rows are populated

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a spreadsheet for a point of sale system. On the 'sales' sheet I have a command button for when a sale is complete. When clicked all of the data from that sheet moves into another sheet 'today's sales' and I need help with vba code to assign a receipt number to each completed sale. The first sale of the day should be receipt no. 1 and each thereafter goes up by 1. Some of the code on that command button is as below:

```
Dim ReceiptNumber As Long

ReceiptNumber = Sheets("Today's sales").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value + 1

For Each c In Sheets("Today's sales").Range("A:A")
If c <> 0 And c.Offset(, 6) = 0 Then
c.Offset(, 6) = ReceiptNumber
End If
Next
```

But this doesn't work for the first sale of the day because column G has a title 'receipt number' - the code can't add 1 to this value.

Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Comment: Well, off top of head, store right(cell,1) on the receipt number cell to a variable, add 1 to it then do a receipt number & variable for your new line. Edit: vba may be overkill here. Just have a hidden column that increments by 1 then do an append to corresponding cell of said column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your first line to this:

```
ReceiptNumber = Val(Sheets("Today's sales").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You truly are an excel hero.

Comment: Huh how would this work if the cell reads "receipt number - #" ? Guess I misunderstood question XD

Comment: Her code would not work because adding 1 to a text value raises an error. It's only the column header that has text. So Val() coverts a text value (that does not look like a number) to a numeric zero. After that, the adding 1 works.

Comment: Yeaaaa, just realized what she meant by title. Header XD Thought she meant each cell read "receipt number #" Edit: yea, VBA is overkill here XD

Answer (score 0):

Loop the rows assigning each receipt a receipt number.

```
Dim lRow as Long
Dim lReceipt as Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Today's sales")

'You can set this to start at whatever row you want.
lRow = 2

lReceipt = 1

'Loop through and rows and add a receipt number to ColumnA
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

   'Put the receipt number in cell A of the current row.
   ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = lReceipt

   lReceipt = lReceipt + 1
   lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```